# All JIRA issues which changed status in last one hour

Tags: jira, jql

I want to find all the issues which changed the status during last one hour. I can get the list of issues updated in last one hour by using

```
updated >=-1h
```

but this also give issues which are updated but status not changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try the following query:

```
updated >= -1h and status CHANGED
```

Reference: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA061/Advanced+Searching